# update server once a second and not more - in python

Tags: python

I have a client code that sniffes network traffic and saves in a dictionary - all the active IP adresses that send packets.
When a new IP adress sends packet - I save it in the dictionary and send the updated dictionary to a HTTP server.
The problem - I don't want to send update more than once in a second. and sometimes there many new IP addresses within miliseconds, so I can't send after every update.
any way to schedule it in python so that he will sendonce a second or less?
thank you

Comment: You can use a buffer to store the new IPs, when the buffer is full or has been more than 1 second since the last data was sent, you send the dictionary to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved by appending the new entries in a list and sending the whole list after each second.

The list can be global and the function can be like this. You can pass this function in a separate thead

```
import time
def sendafterasecond():
   while True:
      if len(data_list) > 0:
         send(data_list)
         data_list = [] # empty it again
      time.sleep(1)
```